# Phonegap 3 - Android Plugin not working

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, phonegap-plugins

I have developed a custom phonegap plugin for android -

https://github.com/bharatkaushik/AndroidEstimoteBeacons

I have placed my plugin folder, within my project's Phonegap's plugin folder.

My project's config.xml entry for this plugin is as follows:

```
 <feature name="EstimoteBeacons">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.bkaushik.estimotebeacons" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

I am not able to see my plugin's java files in my android project.

Also, when I try to see the list of plugins by typing phonegap local plugin list, I get an error that the project directory could not be found.

Am I missing anything here ?

Thanks!
Bharat

Answer (score 1):

I'am using Sencha Cmd v4.0.2.67, sencha touch 2.3, phonegap 3.3.0. I'm also confusing about adding phonegap plugins, but i just find a way, maybe it can be some solutions. My solutions, is change the working directory to phonegap (i have sencha app and phogegap generated application). Then on that directory, just type plugin you want to add, in example:

```
tigalima:phonegap bee$ phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
[phonegap] adding the plugin: org.apache.cordova.network-information
[phonegap] successfully added the plugin
```

hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing your plugin in the plugins directory, move the files to a directory outside of your project root and run this command from your project root:

```
cordova plugin add /PATH/TO/YOUR/PLUGIN/FILES
```

This will add the files to your plugins directory AND to the correct locations for the platform files and JS file.

Comment: That did not work for me. I still get the same error, that the project directory count not be found. In-fact, I am not able to add any of the standard plugins, like camera, etc...

Comment: How did you create your project? cordova create ProjectPath ?

Comment: No. I used sencha cmd to create the project, used the sencha cmd command to enable phonegap for that project

Comment: Ah, sorry not familiar with Sencha. do you see a .cordova or .phonegap directory in your project path?

Comment: Yes. I see a phonegap directory added in my project. In-fact, I had developed an iOS project using the same framework on the same machine. And I was able to add all plugins then :( Not sure what's happening now

Comment: can you build to project for android w/o the plugin? Maybe android didn't add correctly. I know 3.2.0 is having issues with adding android as a platform

Comment: Yes. I am able to build it successfully. I am using 3.1.0-0.15.0

Answer (score 0):

Is estimotebeacons the java class file of your plugin which extends CordovaPlugin?
If not, make sure to include the class file:

```
<feature name="EstimoteBeacons">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.bkaushik.estimotebeacons.ClassName" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

and also make sure to add it on res/xml/Config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

use this command this will help you  and insure that you are doing in your project directory

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/bharatkaushik/AndroidEstimoteBeacons
```